# IllegalStateException in android while using listview

Tags: android

I have an `activity_A` which contains listView, this listView dynamically increases in size adding 10 items everytime I scroll to the bottom of the list, in the same `activity_A` I have an editTextView and a go_button which searches for the string in the editTextView.

Search is my `activity_B` which has a listView, even this listView dynamically increases in size adding 10 items every time.

My problem is when I want to go back to the `activity_A` from `activity_B` using a button click (not the back button of my device) it gives me this exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.
```

My way of going back to `activity_A` from `activity_B` is:

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity_B.this, activity_A.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

I even tried by removing `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `requestLayout()` for your ListView.